# If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$, then does $\sqrt{\sin\alpha}+\sqrt{\sin\beta}+\sqrt{\sin\gamma}$ reach its maximum when $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, triangles

In any given triangle ($\alpha+\beta+\gamma= \pi$), the following inequality holds:

$$\sin {\alpha}+\sin{\beta}+ \sin{\gamma} \leq \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

with the maximum value of $\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}$ reached at $\alpha=\beta=\gamma= \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Does it, then, follow from the above that the expression

$$\sqrt{\sin {\alpha}}+\sqrt{\sin{\beta}}+ \sqrt{\sin{\gamma}}$$

also reaches its maximum value at $\alpha=\beta=\gamma= \frac{\pi}{3}$?

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the inequality $$\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2}{n}}\geq\frac{a_1+a_2+...a_n}{n}$$where equality occurs if $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$

So$$\frac{\sqrt{\sin \alpha}+\sqrt{\sin \beta}+\sqrt{\sin \gamma}}{3}\leq\sqrt{\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin \beta+\sin \gamma}{3}}\leq\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\times 3}}$$Equality occurs when $\sin \alpha=\sin \beta=\sin \gamma$.

So $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: It appears, the upper limit should be $ \sqrt {\frac {3 \sqrt{3}}{2 \times 3}}$ ?

Comment: @USIKPA You are right. There was a typo. I have edited